# Cannot enable or disable extensions after activating CiviMobileAPI

Tags: extension, civimobile

I observe the same behaviour related to CiviMobileAPI that was described for a Wordpress installation of CiviCRM in this civicrm.stackexchange.com question: [Can't enable or disable extensions after migrating from Drupal to Wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/43471/14256).

Our setup is Drupal 9.5.3, CiviCRM 5.58.1, PHP 8.1.11 and CiviMobileAPI 6.1.2

Is this the right place for this issue or should I directly file a bug with the developers of the extension on GitHub?

Comment: They are more likely to see it in GitHub so you would be welcome to add it there (and welcome - good sleuthing)

Comment: I opened a new issue over at the [civimobileapi repo](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/78).